# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class crewcut

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

As per stated in the title,
as I were to continue to next supposed section in the coding. The RMI system did not the display the action based on my input. I want it to display the next part of the coding when the system recognized the input as Customer / Barbershop.

How do i make it show the next case statement?

Client

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class crewcut_client {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to CrewCut Service");
        System.out.println("Are you a 'CUSTOMER' | 'BARBER' ? Type in below");
        String resp = sc.next();

        crewcut cc = (crewcut) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/CrewCut");
        switch (resp){
            case "CUSTOMER":
            case "customer":
            case "Customer":
            {
                System.out.println("Hello Customer !");
                System.out.println("Welcome to our system");
                System.out.println("Please enter your name :");
                String name = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter your contact num :");
                String num = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Here are our services :");
                System.out.println("Hair Cut RM15");
                System.out.println("Hair Wash RM20");
                System.out.println("Hair Dye RM25");
                System.out.println("Press '1' for Hair Cut");
                System.out.println("Press '2' for Hair Wash");
                System.out.println("Press '3' for Hair Dye");
                String service = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Your day of booking ? Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |Saturday | Sunday");
                String day = sc.next();
                //impl code
                System.out.println(cc.check_client(name,num,service,day));
            break;
            }
            case "BARBER":
            case "barber":
            case "Barber":
            {
                System.out.println("Hello Barber !");
                System.out.println("Are you in for work today? Enter 'Y' for YES or 'N' for NO" );
                String attend = sc.nextLine();
                if (attend.equals("Y")){
                    System.out.println("Welcome to work ! ");
                    System.out.println("The shop shall be closed in 9pm");
                }else if (attend.equals("N")){
                    System.out.println("Hope to see you soon !");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (RemoteException re){
        re.printStackTrace();
    }catch (NotBoundException nbe){
        nbe.printStackTrace();
    }catch(MalformedURLException mfe){
        mfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Server

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class crewcut_server {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        crewcutimpl ccl = new crewcutimpl();
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/CrewCut",ccl);
    }catch (RemoteException re){
        re.printStackTrace();
    }catch (MalformedURLException mfe){
        mfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Implementation

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class crewcutimpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements crewcut{
public  crewcutimpl() throws RemoteException{
    super();
}
public String check_client (String name, String num, String service, String day){
    String display;
    int price = 0;
    switch (service){
        case "1":
            price = 15;
            break;
        case "2" :
            price = 20;
            break;
        case "3":
            price = 25;
            break;
    }display =" Your booking has been entered into the system Mr/Mrs " + name + "\n We shall contact 
     you through this num : " + num + "\n Service wanted : "+ service + "Total price :" + price +"Day 
     of appointment :" + day;
    return display;

    }
    }
```

Interface

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

 public interface crewcut {

public String check_client(String name, String num, String service, String day) throws 
RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you follow the Java naming conventions when defining classes?

Comment: can you further explain this?

Comment: Class and interface names should start with a capital letter, underscores are rarely used.

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you for pointing that out. Here is a new problem :

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class Crewcut (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 and Crewcut are in unnamed module of loader
'app')

it said the problem lays in the Naming.lookup in the client class

Comment: `public interface crewcut` must extend `Remote`. I'm surprised you didn't get an error when exporting, or that if you did you didn't mention it here.

Answer (score 1):

Interface must have "extends Remote" that should solve your 2nd problem
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class..."